# Select2 - Searching wildcard matches

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 to style my select box and add functionality and I am wondering how I can make the search rules more lenient. Currently if I have "New Mexico" in the dropdown, I can search for "mexico" or "new mexico" to match the select option, but if I enter "mexico new" I get "no results found." Is there a way to extend the search functionality to match search words regardless of their order?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".states").select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="states" style="width: 50%">
  <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
  <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
  <option value="TB">Tshirt, Black</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't know whether it sounds nice but you can split the search terms and then search for separate terms...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alright, apparently you can set [custom matchers](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#matcher) to accomplish this. I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31626588/2827407) and it seems to be working as desired:

```js
$(function () { 
    $('.states').select2({
        matcher: function (params, data) {
            if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
                return data;
            }

            keywords=(params.term).split(" ");

            for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
                if (((data.text).toUpperCase()).indexOf((keywords[i]).toUpperCase()) == -1) 
                return null;
            }
            return data;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="states" style="width: 50%">
  <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
  <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
  <option value="TB">Tshirt, Black</option>
</select>
```